# How to write this C# code in F#

Tags: c#, f#, try-catch, mutable

I'm used to write code like this in C#:

```cs
SomeObj obj;
try{
    // this may throw SomeException
    obj = GetSomeObj();
}catch(SomeException){
    // Log error...
    obj = GetSomeDefaultValue();
}

obj.DoSomething();
```

This is the way I translated it in F# (obj being a list):

```fs
let mutable obj = []
try
    obj <- getSomeObj
with
    | ex ->
        // Log ex
        obj <- getSomeDefaultValue

doSomething obj
```

Is there any way to do this in F# without using a mutable variable? Is there a more 'elegant' way to handle this situation in F#?

Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The F#-ish way is to return the same type of expression in both branches:

```ml
let obj =
    try
        getSomeObj()
    with
    | ex ->
        // Log ex
        getSomeDefaultValue()

doSomething obj
```

In F#, you can handle exceptions using `option` type. This is an advantage when there is no obvious default value, and the compiler forces you to handle exceptional cases.

```ml
let objOpt =
    try
        Some(getSomeObj())
    with
    | ex ->
        // Log ex
        None

match objOpt with
| Some obj -> doSomething obj
| None -> (* Do something else *)
```

Comment: Great! I knew there must be a way to do this in a F#-ish way!

I'm learning F# and I still haven't got used to think in a functional way. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Wrapping this logic in functions...

```
let attempt f = try Some(f()) with _ -> None
let orElse f = function None -> f() | Some x -> x
```

...it could be:

```
attempt getSomeObj |> orElse getSomeDefaultValue
```

Comment: Although I've chosen some other user answer as valid I really like the way `attempt` was written. I never thought about writing something like that.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. pad's answer illustrates the crux of the solution: everything is an expression in F#, but I wanted to point out the patterns involved. Primitives like these can be handy, and lead to more readable code, on occasion.